# Express: why is this GET request executed twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, pug

I have some code written in Jade, with a link in it. The destination of the link is generated by Jade. When the link is clicked, I notice from my console that the GET-request is being executed twice.

> Why is this? How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

**Jade file:**

```
ul.media-list
    each paper in paperList
        div.panel.panel-default
            div.panel-body
                li.media
                    div.media-left.media-middle
                        a(href='/publication/view/#{paper.id}')
                            | Some image
                    div.media-body
                        div.btn-group(role='group')
                            //!!! When this link is being clicked, GET is executed twice !!!
                            a.btn.btn-default(href='/publication/view/#{paper.id}')
                                | View
```

**Console:**

```
GET /publication/view/123 200 490ms - 5623
GET /publication/view/123 304 458ms - -
```

**app.js:**

```
var publication = require('./routes/publication');
app.use('/publication', publication);
```

**publication.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/view/:id', function (req, res) {
    var data;
    //Some database functions here
    //Just an example
    res.render('publication', {someData: data});
});
```

Comment: Are media-left and media-body overlapping somehow? A click event might fire for both of the links in that case.

Comment: No, media-left and media-body are 2 separate divs. I just checked in the generated HTML.

Comment: Where is `router` defined?

Comment: @ExplosionPills See my edit to `publication.js`

Comment: @JNevens You can do a curl request `curl {baseURL}/publication/view/#{paper.id}` with some dummy paper.id to narrow down problem to either front end or backend.
Also try logging `request.url`, there are some instances where one extra request is made to get favicon.

Comment: it seems, by default, express sends a request to `/favicon.ico`. to prevent this when debugging, you can add `if(req.url === '/favicon.ico'){res.send('').end(); return;}` to the top of the callback function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's just a hypothesis, but it looks like your browser is using some kind of prediction algorithm to pre-load your links even before you click them. [Google Chrome do such things](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1385029?hl=en).

Express.js answered the second response with `304 Not Modified` response, which indicates that it was sent with valid [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) value to validate previously cached response.

Try to disable network actions prediction in your browser. Here is how it looks in Google Chrome settings (`Settings` -> `Show advanced settings...`):

[image: Google Chrome network actions prediction]

Or you may try to verify that the first request is being sent before you're actually clicking on a link by hovering your mouse over it, but not clicking it.

Comment: I think this option may be called "Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly" now?

Answer (score 0):

Its issue of Chrome not happening in Firefox or explorer

Comment: please use the comments to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The html page I am sending contains...
-image width="50" height="50" src='doesnt exist'-

cause -> get resource will be called twice.

if src="" is empty or src="image exists"

get resource will be called only once...
so a missing image url cause in my case this issue...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).